# Calculating the most commonly fired event, per user, in a time period

Tags: google-bigquery

I am pulling a list of UserIDs from a site who have fired specific Google Analytics events during the last few weeks. I currently have this working with the query below, returning one row per userid, per event label.

I would like to enhance this query by calculating the most commonly clicked event per userid in this period and only returning this, rather than all the events that fired for them. Can anyone suggest a good way to achieve this?

```
SELECT customDimension.value AS UserID, hits.eventinfo.eventAction AS Size
FROM `*.ga_sessions_*` AS t
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hits) AS hits
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(t.customdimensions) AS customDimension
WHERE (_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170601' AND '20170628')
AND (hits.page.pagePath LIKE "%/shorts%" OR hits.page.pagePath LIKE "%/t-shirts%")
AND hits.eventinfo.eventCategory = "SIZE Filter Click"
AND (hits.eventinfo.eventAction = "S" OR hits.eventinfo.eventAction = "M" OR hits.eventinfo.eventAction = "L" OR hits.eventinfo.eventAction = "XL")
AND customDimension.index = 2
GROUP BY UserID, Size
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might work for you:

```
WITH data AS(
  select ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>> [STRUCT(NULL as index, '' as value), STRUCT(0 as index, 'test' as value), STRUCT(2 as index, 'user_1' as value)] customDimensions,  ARRAY<STRUCT<page STRUCT<pagePath STRING>, eventinfo STRUCT<eventcategory STRING, eventaction STRING> >> [STRUCT(STRUCT('/home' as pagePath) as page, STRUCT("cat1" as eventcategory, "act1" as eventaction) as eventinfo), STRUCT(STRUCT('/abcshortsabc' as pagePath) as page, STRUCT("SIZE Filter Click" as eventcategory, "S" as eventaction) as eventinfo), STRUCT(STRUCT('/abcshortsabc' as pagePath) as page, STRUCT("SIZE Filter Click" as eventcategory, "S" as eventaction) as eventinfo), STRUCT(STRUCT('/abcshortsabc' as pagePath) as page, STRUCT("SIZE Filter Click" as eventcategory, "M" as eventaction) as eventinfo), STRUCT(STRUCT('/abc/t-shirtsabc' as pagePath) as page, STRUCT("SIZE Filter Click" as eventcategory, "L" as eventaction) as eventinfo)] hits union all
  select ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>> [STRUCT(2 as index, 'user_2' as value)] customDimensions,  ARRAY<STRUCT<page STRUCT<pagePath STRING>, eventinfo STRUCT<eventcategory STRING, eventaction STRING> >> [STRUCT(STRUCT('shorts' as pagePath) as page, STRUCT("cat1" as eventcategory, "act1" as eventaction) as eventinfo), STRUCT(STRUCT('/abcshortsabc' as pagePath) as page, STRUCT("SIZE Filter Click" as eventcategory, "M" as eventaction) as eventinfo), STRUCT(STRUCT('/abcshortsabc' as pagePath) as page, STRUCT("SIZE Filter Click" as eventcategory, "M" as eventaction) as eventinfo), STRUCT(STRUCT('/abcshortsabc' as pagePath) as page, STRUCT("SIZE Filter Click" as eventcategory, "M" as eventaction) as eventinfo), STRUCT(STRUCT('/abc/t-shirtsabc' as pagePath) as page, STRUCT("SIZE Filter Click" as eventcategory, "L" as eventaction) as eventinfo)] hits
)

SELECT 
  (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(customDimensions) WHERE index = 2 GROUP BY value) UserID,
  (SELECT eventinfo.eventaction size FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE (REGEXP_CONTAINS(page.pagepath, r'shorts') OR REGEXP_CONTAINS(page.pagepath, r'/t-shirts')) AND eventinfo.eventcategory = 'SIZE Filter Click' GROUP BY eventinfo.eventaction ORDER BY COUNT(eventinfo.eventaction) DESC LIMIT 1) most_clicked_size
FROM data
```

If you want to retrieve also the amount of total clicks for the most frequent label (action in your case), you can also do:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(customDimensions) WHERE index = 2 GROUP BY value) UserID,
  (SELECT AS STRUCT eventinfo.eventaction size, count(1) freq FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE (REGEXP_CONTAINS(page.pagepath, r'shorts') OR REGEXP_CONTAINS(page.pagepath, r'/t-shirts')) AND eventinfo.eventcategory = 'SIZE Filter Click' GROUP BY eventinfo.eventaction ORDER BY COUNT(eventinfo.eventaction) DESC LIMIT 1) most_clicked_size
FROM data
```

Where `data` is a simulation of your actual ga sessions data.

Comment: Thanks Will, this looks great, how can I adjust this to show all the UserIDs in a date range?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by retrieving UserIds in date range but in `ga_sessions` you have the `Date` field which you can use in your `SELECT` statements as well as in the `WHERE` filtering clauses.